# three.js - Quaternions for rotation matrix of a mesh in relation to the camera when that mesh has a parent?

Tags: matrix, three.js, rotation, quaternions

From a tracking system I have access to a neck 4x4 transform matrix in relation to the camera (NeckWRTCameraMatrix).

I need to animate in three.js the neck bone that has as parent other bone but in a way that the rotation of the neck is in relation to the camera.

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.fromArray(NeckWRTCameraMatrix);

var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(m);

head.boneByName("Joint_Neck").quaternion.copy(quaternion);
```

However this rotates the bone in 180 degrees.
How do I apply the rotation wrt camera as the rotations are in relation to the parent?

Thank you

EDIT: So probably what I need is get the rotation of the neck wrt camera in relation to the world..  some operation between the camera rotation transform and the matrix I got ?

Comment: Don't we need to know the statement that creates NeckWRTCameraMatrix?

Comment: It's a 4x4 Matrix that represents the transform of the neck in relation to the camera

Answer (score 1):

After researching I got there this way, might help someone with quaternion problems:

1. Extracted quaternion from the first frame rotation matrix and conjugated it to get the inverse direction rotation. This will work as the initial pose quaternion

   ```
   initial_quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
   initial_quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(m);
   initial_quaternion.conjugate();
   ```
2. For each frame extracted the quaternion and **multiplied** for the first quaternion, so I got the **composed rotation of both quaternions** (being the first inverted, that conjugation will give the difference from the initial rotation instead of the sum). As I wanted the rotation of neck bone in relation to head bone, this works great.

   ```
   var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();  
   quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(m);
   quaternion.multiply(initial_quaternion);
   ```
3. After having that, as the head and neck movement have a composed rotation of 50% of the total movement, I wanted to give a **50% weight to the rotation**. To that, **interpolated a neutral pose quaternion by the resulted quaternion in 2 with t = 0.5**

   ```
   var basicQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
   quaternion.slerp(basicQuaternion,0.5);
   ```
4. Applied that quaternion to both neck and head bones (axis in the mesh are different from the ones as input) .

   ```
   head.boneByName("Joint_Head").quaternion.set(
         quaternion.y,
         quaternion.z,
         quaternion.x,
         quaternion.w
   );

   head.boneByName("Joint_Neck").quaternion.set(
         quaternion.y,
         quaternion.z,
         quaternion.x,
         quaternion.w
   );
   ```